# How to configure spring-boot with embedded Tomcat to work as a single application?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, spring-boot

I have application which after `mvn clean package -U tomcat7:run` works as soap web service and wsdl is available on: http://localhost:8080/appservices/ws?wsdl

Now my aim to compile a single jar which will provide web service after execute `java -jar service.jar`.

As I know spring-boot decides this task.

I created an Application class:

```
package com.comp.service;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

But after I execute `mvn spring-boot:run` and call url http://localhost:8080/appservices/ws?wsdl I receive:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Feb 05 14:54:11 MSK 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Spring's start log:

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.2.RELEASE)

2016-02-05 14:43:45.012  INFO 21008 --- [           main] com.comp.service.Application        : Starting Application on PCwith PID 21008 (C:\Users\Maya\git\app-services\target\classes started by Maya in C:\Users\Maya\git\app-services
-services)
2016-02-05 14:43:45.017  INFO 21008 --- [           main] com.comp.service.Application        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-02-05 14:43:45.117  INFO 21008 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5dc33359: startup date [Fri Feb 05 14:43:45 MSK 2016]; root o
f context hierarchy
2016-02-05 14:43:46.344  INFO 21008 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=fal
se; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; des
troyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; depen
dencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); de
fined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-02-05 14:43:47.363  INFO 21008 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-02-05 14:43:47.386  INFO 21008 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-02-05 14:43:47.388  INFO 21008 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
2016-02-05 14:43:47.555  INFO 21008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-02-05 14:43:47.559  INFO 21008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2448 ms
2016-02-05 14:43:48.048  INFO 21008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-02-05 14:43:48.055  INFO 21008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-02-05 14:43:48.055  INFO 21008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-02-05 14:43:48.056  INFO 21008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-02-05 14:43:48.057  INFO 21008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-02-05 14:43:48.475  INFO 21008 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5dc33359: startup date [Fri Feb 05 14:43:
45 MSK 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-02-05 14:43:48.589  INFO 21008 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigur
e.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-02-05 14:43:48.592  INFO 21008 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorControlle
r.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-02-05 14:43:48.639  INFO 21008 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-02-05 14:43:48.639  INFO 21008 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-02-05 14:43:48.694  INFO 21008 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-02-05 14:43:48.869  INFO 21008 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-02-05 14:43:48.967  INFO 21008 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-02-05 14:43:48.972  INFO 21008 --- [           main] com.comp.service.Application        : Started Application in 4.428 seconds (JVM running for 11.125)
2016-02-05 14:44:02.085  INFO 21008 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-02-05 14:44:02.086  INFO 21008 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-02-05 14:44:02.107  INFO 21008 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms
```

Where is my problem? In Application.class?

My pom:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <jdkName>JavaSE-1.7</jdkName>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>


        <spring-boot.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>

    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>

                    <extraDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                            <version>1.7.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                            <version>1.7.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.7</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.7</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </extraDependencies>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thank you for any advice.

**UPDATE**

May be problem in web.xml?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems,
Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            <!--com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet-->
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
        public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
            factory.setPort(9000);
            factory.setSessionTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/notfound.html"));
            return factory;
        }

    }
```

`spring-boot:run` log:

```
2016-02-08 10:26:19.733  INFO 3976 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-02-08 10:26:19.758  INFO 3976 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2016-02-08 10:26:19.990  INFO 3976 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9000 (http)
2016-02-08 10:26:19.998  INFO 3976 --- [           main] com.comp.service.Application        : Started Application in 5.911 seconds (JVM running for 15.537)
2016-02-08 10:26:53.130  INFO 3976 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-02-08 10:26:53.130  INFO 3976 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-02-08 10:26:53.156  INFO 3976 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 26 ms
```

Comment: For starters remove the tomcat plugin and configure Jax-WS properly. There is a huge difference starting the embedded tomcat with Spring boot and how it works with tomcat (as you initially did).

Comment: And remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` of the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency to include Tomcat in your JAR.

Comment: @M. Deinum, `tomcat7-maven-plugin` removed from pom.

Comment: You might want to add the actuator to the project because it gives you insight into configuration and endpoints created.

Comment: @Marged i didn't understand : `Spring Boot Actuator includes a number of additional features to help you monitor and manage your application when it’s pushed to production`, but i want to create a single jar application to provide customers with web service.

Comment: Like I said: it gives you details about the internals of your application, like http endpoints and auto configuration. And as you are obviously having problems with one of those ...

Comment: @Marged added. But http://localhost:8080/info returns {}

Comment: If you use a standalone JAR with embedded Tomcat, your web.xml is not used. You should register your WS listener in the Java configuration.

Comment: Info is mostly empty. Use metrics, configprops, beans, logfile ...

Comment: @Dunni thank you. I'll try to improve Application.class with ws listener and return here with results.

Comment: @Marged, it seems that actuator is debugging tool for webapps. Will try to use it. Thank you.

Comment: @dunni , please look on the Update 1. Could you help me with the next steps? Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners

Comment: @dunni , can't understand what to do with web.xml?

Comment: Use the ServletListenerRegistrationBean to register the `WSServletContextListener`, as described in the reference documentation, and remove the web.xml, since it's ignored by the embedded container.

Comment: @dunni look what i found https://github.com/dlizarra/spring-boot-cxf-integration-noxml